# Infix to postfix left one parentheses at the end when expression is fully enclosed

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, postfix-notation, shunting-yard

I'm working on a problem in my data structures class and I've managed to do most it in terms of implementing the algorithm and getting the core logic sorted. But one problem that I keep running into is when the expression being converted is fully surrounded by parentheses. Such as in the case of (2+2). The correct conversion to postfix would be 2 2 +. But my program will output 2 2 + (.

It does not do this for all pairs of parentheses, only in the unique case of a fully enclosed expression, meaning that something such as 1/(2+3) will be fine

For context, this implementation uses a linked queue to store the output. The functions relating to getting priority or type were given to us by the professor, and should be fine.

All I can gather right now is that at some point the lone left parentheses is getting enqueued by accident, though I fail to see any portion of the program where this could happen aside from the last cleanup that enqueues all that is left in the stack. But I tried to look into that, and despite what I did, the parentheses remains.

As a note, we are supposed to assume optimal or "perfect" input in this task, hence the lack of consideration of some edge cases and possible error-causing scenarios

As it stands, this is the function

```
QUEUE infix_to_postfix(char *infixstr) {
    char *p = infixstr;
    QUEUE queue = { 0 }; // result postfix expression in queue
    STACK stack = { 0 }; // auxiliary stack
    int sign = 1, num = 0;
    while (*p) { // expression string traversal

        if (*p == '-' && (p == infixstr || *(p - 1) == '(')) { // get the sign of an operand
            sign = -1;
        }

        else if (get_type(*p) == 0) { // namely *p is digit character, aation: use horner’s algorithm to get the operand
            num = *p - '0';
            while ((*(p + 1) >= '0' && *(p + 1) <= '9')) {
                num = num * 10 + *(p + 1) - '0';
                p++;
            }
            enqueue(&queue, new_node(sign * num, 0));
            sign = 1;
        }

        else if (get_type(*p) == 1) { // namely *p is an operator character
            int current_priority = get_priority(*p);
            while (stack.top != NULL && stack.top->data != '('
                    && current_priority <= get_priority(stack.top->data)) {
                enqueue(&queue, pop(&stack));
            }
            push(&stack, new_node(*p, 1));
        }

        else if (get_type(*p) == 2) { // *p == '(‘
            push(&stack, new_node(*p, 2));

        }

        else if (get_type(*p) == 3) { // *p == ‘)‘
            while (stack.top != NULL && stack.top->data != '(') {
                enqueue(&queue, pop(&stack));
            }

            pop(&stack);

        }
// else ignore
        p++; // move to next character
    }
// finally pop each node and insert it to queue
    while (stack.top) {
        enqueue(&queue, pop(&stack));
    }
    return queue;
}
```

Edit:

After tinkering with the code, I've found that part of the issue at least is in the line

```
else if (get_type(*p) == 3) { // *p == ‘)‘
            while (stack.top != NULL && stack.top->data != '(') {
                enqueue(&queue, pop(&stack));
            }

            pop(&stack);
            
        }
```

For some reason in the loop it appears to enqueue the '(' character at the end, this is despite clear instructions in the loop to *not* proceed if the top of the stack is the left bracket.

edit 2:

Per request, I have added more parts and the main program.

Common

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    int type;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

NODE* new_node(int data, int type);
void clean(NODE **npp);
void display(NODE *np);
int get_type(char c);
int get_priority(char op);
```

Full display implementation

```
void display(NODE *np) {
    while (np) {
        if (np->type == 0)
            printf("%d", np->data);
        else
            printf("%c", np->data);

        np = np->next;

        if (np)
            printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Queue

```
typedef struct queue {
    int length;
    NODE *front;
    NODE *rear;
} QUEUE;

void enqueue(QUEUE *qp, NODE *np);
NODE* dequeue(QUEUE *qp);
void clean_queue(QUEUE *qp);
```

Enqueue implementation

```
void enqueue(QUEUE *qp, NODE *np) {
// your code
    if (qp->rear == NULL) {
        qp->front = np;
        qp->rear = np;
    }

    else {
        qp->rear->next = np;
        qp->rear = np;
    }

    qp->length++;

    return;
}
```

stack

```
void push(STACK *sp, NODE *np);
NODE* pop(STACK *sp);
void clean_stack(STACK *sp);
```

Pop stack

```
NODE* pop(STACK *sp) {
// your code
    NODE *return_node;

    if (sp->top == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    else {
        return_node = sp->top;
        sp->top = sp->top->next;
    }

    sp->length--;

    return return_node;
}
```

Main. There are some other unrelated functions in here that work fine and aren't an issue for this question.

```
char *tests[] = { "1+2", "(1+2*3)", "1+(6/3)" };

void test_infix_to_postfix() {
    printf("------------------\n");
    printf("Test: infix_to_postfix\n\n");
    int n = sizeof tests / sizeof *tests;
    QUEUE q = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        q = infix_to_postfix(tests[i]);
        printf("infix_to_postfix(%s): ", tests[i]);
        display(q.front);
        clean_queue(&q);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        test_infix_to_postfix();
        test_evaluate_postfix();
        test_evaluate_infix();
    } else {
        interative_exprssion(args[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are never popping the `(`. This is the Dijkstra shunting-yard algorithm. Look it up.

Comment: @user207421. I thought I was popping it. That's why I included a pop at the end of else if (get_type(*p) == 3)

Comment: No. The pop after that is unconditional. Did you mean to put it inside a block controlled by that `if`? as suggested by the incorrect indentation?

Comment: @user207421 My intention is this:

If we run into a ')' then we pop items from the stack and add them to the output until we either run out of stack, or we reach a '(' in the stack(Which shouldn't be handled by this loop.

Then after that loop, but still in the else if for the ')' case, we do one more pop to get rid of the left bracket

The last pop should be unconditional, at least since we're assuming optimal input. It should always just get rid of the left bracket which should be on top of the stack now

Comment: So you have missing `{` after the `if` and missing `}` after the pop, as the incorrect indentation suggests. Just like `if (get_type(*p) == 1)` in fact. At present the only statement controlled by the `if` is the following `while` loop.

Comment: @user207421 I don't see any issues with missing  { } on my end. Each if/else if has a { and a matching } at the end. The pop should be inside tthe `else if (get_type(*p) == 2) `

Comment: Sigh. I see no `{` after the `if` we are discussing. I do see it is on the `if` further up. I see incorrect indentation. I see code that doesn't agree with your description above. Specifically, "after that loop, but still in the else if for the ')' case, we do one more pop" is false. I've told you how to fix it. If you're just going to argue about it, rather than even bother to try what you're being told here, I don't know why you posted, or why I should bother commenting here.

Comment: @user207421 I don't intended to argue. I just don't identify any issues relating to missing { }. According to the algorithm given 

"When you see a right parenthesis, then pop the stack until you see a matching left parenthesis, which is popped as well. All the popped items are written to the output except the left parenthesis." That is what I am intended to do in that else if. I am using a while loop to pop the stack up until I see a left parentheses, adding the popped elemetns to the output. Then I pop once more to remove the matching parentheses.

Comment: I do want the pop(&stack) to occur *within* `else if (get_type(*p) == 3) `, as the algorithm only calls for that pop to be done in that case, after the rest of the stack up to the left `(` has been popped. But it seems the `{ }` are all in order to me. One set for the else if, and one for the loop

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Please provide the code necessary to compile (definitions of functions and types) and the main code that is necessary to run this function with the example string, and which prints the result

Comment: @trincot I've edited some more things in that should be helpful. I've had trouble with this issue to because if I look at the links in the linked queue, and count out the length of the linked list that is being stored, it seems to not possess this anomalous parentheses. With the linked queue given, if there was an "(" a the end. queue.rear should be "(", but it's instead the final proper value. So it's getting created somewhere. I figured maybe it was the display function doing something weird, but I can't find anything wrong with that. If you need more details like code for display. Do ask!

Comment: Yes, please add the implementations of these functions. In the end, you're asking us to debug your program, so we need to compile it, and so all function definitions are needed. If you call functions that are not related to the problem, then leave them out, like for instance `main` only needs to call `test_infix_to_postfix`. We should be able to copy the code you provide and compile & run it without change, and see the problem occurring.

Comment: @trincot You got it. I've added the code related to display as well as a couple queue and stack functions which belong to the area of the conversion function that seems to be the issue. The rest of the functions work quite similarly to their standard implementations except the stack push for example is given a pre-made node rather than making one inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you transfer a node from the stack to the queue, using a pop-enqueue sequence, the `next` field of the transferred node is still pointing to its successor in the stack. You need to clear that `next` pointer.

You can fix that in `enqueue`, by adding the assignment `np->next = NULL;`

The `push` function will not have that issue. Although you didn't provide the code for that function, it is evident that it will have an assignment like `np->next = sp->top;`, and so the old `next` field value is not bringing havoc like you had in your `enqueue` function.

Comment: Yep! That fixed it right up! Added that one line, and all is clear. Pretty obvious in retrospect, I feel stupid for not seeing it. I think the confusion came down due to a different implementation of the enqueue, since usually when I've made that function, we make the node inside and it always has NULL as next. It wouldn't have shown in my queue tests since I never tested with nodes that were a part of another list like that. Thanks a lot, you've helped me greatly during my time on this site. I just wish I could stop making stupid small oversights like this